# Add widgets to available widgets section without changing the theme?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I have a client that wants to use a particular theme without modification, but will likely want to have more widgets than are available with a given theme.

Is there a way to add widgets to the list of those available without modifying the theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add widgets through plug-ins the same way you add them through themes.  So move the widget code from your `functions.php` file and drop it inside a custom plug-in.  You'll get the same functionality without the need to modify your theme.

Comment: *@EAMann*: But doesn't the theme need to have code to display the widgets? I don't think putting the widget code in plugins is sufficient, or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: So long as the theme has a [widgetized sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes) as most current themes do, then there's nothing more you need to do.  When a widget is registered by a plug-in, it's automatically added to the list of available plug-ins on the Themes >> Widgets page.